# Git command windows 10 slow

Tags: windows, git, performance

I use

- windows 10
- git 2.18.0
- ssh via privat key file with passphrase

all git command are very slow. i have test command by using setting GIT Trace,

[image: git trace command]

i have uninstall and install git

i have uninstall intellij an reinstall it clean

i have test some config, but nothing helps.

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow

but nothing helps.

my config

```html
git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.18.0.windows.1
user.name=Firstname Surname
user.email=firstname.surname@domain.de
credential.helper=manager
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
gc.auto=256

C:\Users\Besitzer>git config --list --global
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.18.0.windows.1
user.name=Firstname Surname
user.email=firstname.surname@domain.de
credential.helper=manager
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
gc.auto=256

C:\Users\Besitzer>git config --list --show-origin
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=openssl
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.18.0.windows.1
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       user.name=Firstname Surname
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       user.email=firstname.surname@domain.de
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       credential.helper=manager
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       core.preloadindex=true
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       core.fscache=true
file:C:/Users/Besitzer/.gitconfig       gc.auto=256
```

have someone any other idea?

```html
$ GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 git pull
07:23:44.194619 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.001251600 s: read cache .git/index
07:23:46.784485 trace.c:420             performance: 0.019059100 s: git command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
07:23:47.493496 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.001326900 s: read cache .git/index
07:23:47.968475 trace.c:420             performance: 0.006132500 s: git command: git gc --auto
07:23:48.305488 trace.c:420             performance: 3.635291700 s: git command: git fetch --update-head-ok
07:23:49.127034 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.001244100 s: read cache .git/index
07:23:49.130536 trace.c:420             performance: 0.015394700 s: git command: git merge FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
07:23:49.473534 trace.c:420             performance: 5.283561100 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe' pull
```

Comment: You may run each step from the trace manually, then you will see where the slowness is.

Comment: I have another machine with same os, git repo and git version. on this, git commands more faster, :-(

Comment: Then it is something we can not help you. You will need to figure out yourself.

Comment: To me, this looks like a combination of a large repo and a slow network connection.

Comment: sry we have more then 5 users, IOS and Windows. They have no problems in the same network. My second Notebook have no problems to.

Comment: Do you maybe have an antivirus on? It may slow down disc access

Comment: i have avast, i hav deinstall but no differnence